# Form event function triggers jquery function

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-events

I have a textbox form that when focused triggers a function, but the problem is this function was inside jQuery function and its not working, see my codes...

```
<input type="text" name="clickMe" onfocus="focusMe()" />
```

I want this text box triggers an event when focused and its the `focusMe()` function, yet I want this function use jQuery that's why I put it under jQuery function...

```
$(function(){

    focusMe(){
      //events happens here
    }

});
```

I know there are jQuery methods to make the focus event happens like `#(element).focus()` function... But I want it be triggered the event using form event like above `onfocus="focusMe()"` ... Anyone can tell me what should I do to the function under jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to wrap jQuery code in `$(function(){` necessarily. Functions, for example, are best suited outside. Here's the code you'll use to make `focusMe` run:

```
var focusMe = function() {
    alert('running');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want that function in the jQuery block.

You can just place it before it and it will be able to use jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it attached as an event, you should use jQuery's .focus() method. You would do it like this:

```
   <input type="text" id="clickme"/>


   (function() {
       $('#clickme').focus( function() {
           alert('focused');
       });
   });
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.